# Nofity User some message from a windows service

Tags: windows-services, notifyicon

I have created a windows service which gets soem info from database and I want to notify user based on the info retreived from the DB. How can I notify user from a windows service using system tray notification? Can you please show me some sample (using IPC mechanism) to get the return value of a method used in a windows service in a system tray notification?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options such as these:

1. **Sockets**: (Not too difficult to write, has firewall problems) You can find samples for it almost everywhere.
2. **External WinForm**: (The easiest method, has security problems and might blocked by
   some antivirus apps) Just create a winForm with the ability to go into
   the windows notification area and then tell the service to run its
   exe file.
3. **Named Pipes**: (Probably the most difficult, but it's the recommended
   solution) [Here is a Code Project sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7176/Inter-Process-Communication-in-NET-Using-Named-Pip).
4. **Other tricks** like: Create a hidden winform project (ShowInTask=false) and put it in StartUp. provide it with a FileSystemWatcher object and make it watch for a certain file which the service creates or deletes it to signal the winform.

Comment: Hi Bizz,
thanks for the options mentioned. Do we need to have a "NamedPipeServerStream " in windows service and "NamedPipeClientStream" in another App which gets the info from the NamedPipeServerStream . I am new to this. Can you please explain me in detail?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to WCF, but I think if you ask another question referring to `NamedPipes` and `WCF` you'll find better answers.