# Windows service open dialog on all logged in sessions

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to pop up a dialog on any logged in session of a workstation, from a windows service?  If so,  any exaples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077709/nofity-user-some-message-from-a-windows-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way would be to have a "notifying" application running for all users, which receives a signal from the service.